# What are the elements of this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, notation, finite-fields

Where $\Bbb F_5$ is the finite field of $5$ elements. I'm not sure what this notation is getting at:

$$ \mathbb F_5 \left(\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

I assumed it was just

$$ \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2&4\\4&3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&3\\3&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

These matrices are nilpotent so multiplying them only generates the $0$ matrix

Comment: Since it's a notation question, that seems like a good question for whoever wrote it -- where'd you get this from? :)

Comment: I assume it means the smallest subring of matrices over $F_5$ that contains the matrix  [1,2,2,4] of your question

Comment: Based on the information given, I'd agree with Amr's interpretation, and then also with your solution because those matrices are pairwise orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a single ironclad interpretation in this case.  Part of the problem is that we don't know if the entries of the matrix are supposed to be from $F_5$ or not, and we don't clearly see what $F_5()$ means.

When $\alpha$ is an element of a field $K$ and $F$ is a field contained in $K$, $F(\alpha)$ usually denotes the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$.  However, no matter what ring you think the coefficients come from, the matrix is not invertible (check the determinant) so it's certainly not an element of a field contained in $M_2(R)$ for any ring $R$.

One could also interpret it as "the smallest $F_5$ algebra of $M_2(F_5)$ containing that matrix" and you'd get the set you gave plus the scalar $2\times 2$ matrices in $M_2(F_5)$.  Another way to think about this is $F_5[X]/(X^2)$ since $X^2$ is the minimal polynomial for this matrix over $F_5$.

One could still interpret it as "the smallest $F_5$ algebra (without identity) of $M_2(F_5)$ containing that matrix" and it would be the set you got (which is a zero ring: $R^2=\{0\}$) but it would not be a unitary algebra or contain any copy of $F_5$ like we usually want with algebras.  Usually this would be denoted as $F_5[\alpha]$ (note the change to brackets.)

One could also try to suppose that the coefficients of the matrix come from a field other than $F_5$ so that maybe it isn't nilpotent, but that raises the question of "if you wanted a matrix of infinite mulitplicative order then why did you pick that matrix then instead of something easy like $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ in $M_2(\mathbb Z)$?"

If I had to guess, I'd pick the one in the third paragraph.

Comment: This answer covers things well, but I do have a modest objection. In particular, when one writes $A[\alpha]$ for some ring $A$ and $\alpha \in B$ for some $A$-algebra $B$, one typically means the image of the unique $A$-algebra hom $A[X] \to B$ sending $X$ to $\alpha$. In particular, $A[\alpha]$ certainly contains a ''copy'' of $A$ via the image of constant polynomials, i.e. things of the form $a\alpha^{0}$ for $a \in A$. In the OP's case, $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^{2} = 0$, but $\alpha \neq 0$, so I think their ring should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{5}[X]/(X^{2})$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's halfway between the two.  I should probably mention it, if you don't mind.

Comment: Although it's hard to guess the intention of the external poser of the question, given the peculiar notation, I'd second @AlexWertheim's idea regarding a dignified interpretation.

Comment: @rschwieb not at all, please do mention it if you agree with my suggestion. (And thanks for the vote of confidence, Paul - I was reticent to make an authoritative suggestion, since I'm also not totally sure what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim You're definitely right. I don't know why it wasn't the first thing I wrote down.